# How to refer gradle plugin generated protobuf files to subproject using SpringCloud Gateway

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, spring-cloud-gateway, grpc-java

I have a gradle muliproject. The root project holds protobuf sources. But when I want to use it in `JsonToGrpc` filter of SpringCloud Gateway, I need to provide the `proto-descriptor` file and the `proto-file` file, how can I specify them in the gateway's configuration?

```
D:.   <- the root project
├─.gradle
├─build
│  ├─classes
│  │  ├─java
│  │  │  └─main
│  |  |      └─cn.remering.kluster.grpc
│  │  └─kotlin
│  │     └─main
│  |         ├─cn.remering.kluster.grpc
│  │         └─META-INF
│  └─generated
│     └─source
│        └─proto
│            └─main
│                ├─grpc
│                │  └─cn.remering.kluster.grpc
│                ├─grpckt
│                │  └─cn.remering.kluster.grpc
│                ├─java
│                │  └─cn.remering.kluster.grpc
│                ├─kotlin
│                |  └─cn.remering.kluster.grpc
|                └-descriptor_set.desc   <--- the proto-descriptor file
├─gradle
│  └─wrapper
├─kluster-skin-auth
|  |
│  └─src
│      ├─main
│      │  ├─kotlin
│      │  │  └─cn.remering.kluster.auth.api
│      │  └─resources
│      └─test
│          ├─kotlin
│          └─resources
├─kluster-skin-gateway   <-- the gateway
│  ├─build
│  │  ├─classes
│  │  │  └─kotlin
│  │  │      └─main
│  │  │          ├─cn.remering.kluster.gateway
│  │  │          └─META-INF
│  │  └─resources
│  │     └─main
│  └─src
│      ├─main
│      │  ├─kotlin
│      │  │  └─cn.remering.kluster.gateway
│      │  └─resources
│      └─test
│          ├─kotlin
│          └─resources
└─src
    └─main
        └─proto   <-- contains the proto-file
```

build.gradle.kts of the root project

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2023.0.0"
extra["springCloudAlibabaVersion"] = "2022.0.0.0"

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.3" apply false
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.22"
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.9.4"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.22" apply false
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        proto {
            srcDir("src/main/proto")
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.25.3"
    }


    plugins {
        create("grpc") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.62.2"
        }
        create("grpckt") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.4.1:jdk8@jar"
        }
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        all().configureEach {
            generateDescriptorSet = true
            plugins {
                create("grpc")
                create("grpckt")
            }
            builtins {
                create("kotlin")
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring")

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        val implementation by configurations
        val api by configurations
        val compileOnly by configurations

        implementation("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.62.2")
        implementation("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:1.4.1")
        implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-kotlin:3.25.3")
        compileOnly("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5")

    }

    tasks.withType<Copy> {
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "org.springframework.boot")
    apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring")

    dependencies {
        val implementation by configurations
        val testImplementation by configurations
        implementation(rootProject)
        implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
        implementation(platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}"))
        implementation(platform("com.alibaba.cloud:spring-cloud-alibaba-dependencies:${property("springCloudAlibabaVersion")}"))
        implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
        implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging-jvm:2.0.11")
        implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap")
        implementation("com.alibaba.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-nacos-discovery")
        implementation("com.alibaba.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-nacos-config")
        testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    }

    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
            jvmTarget = "17"
        }
    }

    tasks.withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}

group = "cn.remering.kluster"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

`application.yaml` of the gateway

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: auth-service
          uri: grpc://kluster-skin-auth
          predicates:
            - Path=/auth/**
          filters:
            - name: JsonToGrpc
              args:
                proto-descriptor: file:<unknown>
                proto-file: file:<unkown>
                service: AuthService
                method: authenticate
```

I asked the ChatGPT 3.5 and still don't know how to refer the `proto-descriptor` file and `proto-file`file.